# Python nested for loop to match strings from a text file to strings in a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, nested-loops

The purpose of my code is to read text file, add the lines into an array, iterate over each element in the array, convert the element to a string, and return lines from csv file that contain this string. My code is:

```
#Read cvs File from url
import csv
import urllib2   
url = 'mycsvfile.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

#Read txt File
import linecache
fileName = 'myfile.txt'
myFile = open(fileName,'r')
list_of_lists = []
try:
    for line in myFile:
        list_of_lists.append(line.strip())

    #Lookup Lines
    for element in list_of_lists:
        elementstring=''.join(element)
        for row in cr:
            if elementstring in row:
                print row


finally:
    myFile.close()
```

The code does not display anything.

Comment: I can't see any obvious problems. Why don't you add some `print repr(elementstring)` and `print repr(row)` to see whether the elements actually match?

Comment: BTW, your `list_of_lists` will not hold lists but just strings, so the `''.join` is pretty pointless. Also, why create `list_of_lists` at all, instead of just iterating the file directly?

Comment: I agree with @tobias_k and would add one thing: Have you used a Python debugger? A debugger lets you step through your code line by line and look at all your variables each step of the way. It's a great way to understand what your code is really doing, so you don't have to say "it doesn't work and I don't know why." I wrote about [a few Python debuggers here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16474706/1202830).

Comment: @tobias_k i have tried replacing 'elementstring=''.join(element)' with elementstring='ExistingStringInFile', it does find the string and show all data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that in the first iteration of the csv reader you do not have any rows that satisfy the condition - `if elementstring in row:` (for the first `elementstring` ) . After this iteration, you have exhausted your csv and it has reached the end, trying to iterate over it again does not work.

Try openning the url and csv outside the loop and convert each inner row into a set and then add them all into a list, and then use that to loop -

```
#Read cvs File from url
import csv
import urllib2   
url = 'mycsvfile.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)
csvset = [set(i) for i in cr]

#Read txt File
import linecache
fileName = 'myfile.txt'
myFile = open(fileName,'r')
list_of_lists = []
try:
    for line in myFile:
        list_of_lists.append(line.strip())

    #Lookup Lines
    for element in list_of_lists:
        elementstring=''.join(element)
        for row in csvset:
            if elementstring in row:
                print row


finally:
    myFile.close()
```

Comment: Yes, that might be the problem! However, I would suggest adding the lines from the text file to a set (if it's not too much), iterating the CSV file in the outer loop, and looking up the elements in the csv rows in that set. Might be a bit faster.

Comment: @tobias_k i will also try what you suggested above because it is a bit slow to get the data.

Comment: @user2842033 I added the using of sets in my answer, please try that.