# Python: Issue with Elif Break

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple program that will take all of your lottery numbers, and compare them (using set intersect) with the winning numbers that you input.

I've gotten the groundwork laid where you enter your numbers, it gets submitted to a sublist, which will then be converted into five separate sets, which will be used to compare. However, when you run the script, the while loop will not break when the length of the list is 5 (this is the goal).

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Or maybe even a better way of working this whole program. I'm relatively new to the world of Python, I'm just diving in, and trying to make this program work.

```
# Start Program 
def set_convert(list):
    conversion = set(list)
    return conversion

def comparison(winning_numbers, my_numbers):
    pass

def main():
    print('Welcome to the Lottery Checker v1.0!')

    winning_numbers = [int(x) for x in input('Enter the winning numbers(Sep w/ Spaces): ').split()]

    winning_set = set_convert(winning_numbers)

    my_numbers = []

    while True:
        numbers = [int(x) for x in input('Enter your numbers(Sep w/ Spaces Max: 5): ').split()]

        if len(numbers) == 6:
            my_numbers.append(numbers)
            print('Added! Want to add more?')
        elif len(my_numbers) == 5:
            break
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

    print('Here are your numbers: {}. Good luck! :-)'.format(my_numbers))


main()
```

Comment: Why are you checking `len(numbers) == 6` when you say "Max: 5"?

Comment: Try printing `my_numbers` just before the `if` clause and inspect. What do you get?

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? I think that's the thing you should learn right now. By stepping through your code with a visual debugger you can see at a glance what is happening with all of your variables and program logic. I posted some [suggestions for Python visual debuggers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473278/python-visual-debugger) a while back. I urge you to take a look at that answer, pick any of the debuggers listed, and step through your code. You will learn a lot about how to troubleshoot problems like this.

Comment: If you like any of the responses below, please accept them :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
elif len(my_numbers) == 5:
```

with

```
elif len(numbers) == 5:
```

Also, it is advisable that you don't use the keyword `list` as an argument for the function `set_convert`. Rather, define it as:

```
def set_convert(mylist):
    conversion = set(mylist)
    return conversion
```

And finally, you don't need to pass in `my_numbers` and `winning_numbers` into the function `comparison` as arguments since they are available in the outer scope.