# Unabe to loop over files with Python

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I have a folder with 40 files in it which I want to loop through. When I print out the name of the file my code works fine:

```
import os
source = 'pathtofile'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source):
    for file in filenames:
        print file
```

It will print :

File1

File2

File 3

.....

File 40

But if I try to open the file / files in the loop I get the following error. IO error: **IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'**

This is the code I am having issues with :

```
import os
import re

destdir = 'pathtofile'
files = [ f for f in os.listdir(destdir) if 
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(destdir,f)) ]

for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as var1:
        for line in var1: 
            if re.match('(.*)exception(.*)', line):
                print line
```

I have verified , and the string I am searching for, it does exist in the files.

Can you please provide some insight as to what is wrong with my code ? Thanks.

Comment: `f` is still just the filename because you define it that way:  `for f in filenames:`  Why did you replace the `with open(...) as f:` line with `log = open(...)` line?

Comment: Thanks Huck . I was experimenting with both, since on some posts I read it needed the full path and tried with and without the full path.

Comment: Yes, but the `log =` messed it up. You don't use `log` anywhere, and when you do `for line in f`, `f` is the _filename_. Your first attempt was closer, but was missing the full path.

Comment: What they are getting at is just replace your `log` statement with the `open` statement in the original code and it should work.

Comment: Also do you have a Python debugger and know how to use it? Single stepping through your code will be immensely helpful. Here are some [notes on a few Python debuggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16474706/1202830). That post is a bit old and doesn't include some more recent Python debuggers such as the ones available for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGeary . I have added my updated code, but still the same issue.

Comment: Thanks @Tony . I have updated my code but still the same issue.

Comment: Because you got rid of the `os.path.join(...)` call again.

Comment: Really, go get one of those Python debuggers and learn how to step through your code and look at variables along the way. It will make things so easy for you!

Comment: @MichaelGeary, Thanks for your suggestion Michael. You are correct. I need to learn how to use the debugger. Also, I took a look at the post u suggested but seems Winpdb is down, do you know of another site I can download it from ?

Comment: Good question on Winpdb - you're right, the site does seem to be down. For a more modern option I think I would suggest Visual Studio Code and Don Jayamanne's Python extension from the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Just noticed that winpdb.org is back up, but it is really old. I would definitely suggest a more up to date debugger, like the VS Code one I mentioned. Or if you are on Windows, the full Visual Studio Community Edition with its Python add-in.

Comment: @MichaelGeary, Thanks for you Suggestion. I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
from os.path import join, isfile

files = [join(destdir, x) for x in os.listdir(destdir) if isfile(join(destdir, x))]
```

or if you know all files have `.txt` extension, you can do:

```
from glob import glob

files = glob(join(destdir, '*.txt'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!! It is working now. So, for the record, when working with files, we need to add the full path every single time ?

Comment: You're welcome.  `listdir` returns only names of content files/directories in the given path. Please check the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

Comment: I will definitely do that.