# Search for a Python Visual Debugger on Cygwin

Tags: python, debugging, cygwin

**Question**

As a Python Developer on Windows. I need a visual debugger for Python that is running in the Cygwin-Terminal.

**Context:**

In my Company we are on windows and using Cygwin. The Python code we have havely relies on the Cygwin Terminal (f.e `subprocess.call("cygpath -w ...")`). At the moment i'm using pdb for debugging but i don't like it, i would prefer a visual debugger.

**I've tried so far:**

- using idle3 from cygwin via X-Win Server. But the experiance was to painfull (bad windows layout, missing shortcuts, ... ), so i returned to pdb.
- Try to get Cygwin as my Debug-Terminal in VS Code and PyCharm. I managed to get the cygwin terminal as a terminal there, but i cannot debug from this point. (f.e. I set in PyCharm Tools->Terminal->ShellPath path to cygwin shell)

**I'm aware of some other topics related to visual debugger as here:**

- [Python Visual Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473278/python-visual-debugger)

but those topics did not match that cygpath and the other cyg* functions are available.

Comment: I don't really have answer for your specific question, but as a shameless plug, if you're doing lots of `subprocess.call("cygpath...)` you may find [PyCygwin](https://pycygwin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) useful.  It provides Python bindings for Cygwin's C API so you can do things like path conversion without invoking a subprocess (in fact that's currently its most useful feature; I only plan to add more features as needed).

Comment: This is very useful to know, i were not aware of your lib. Thank you for your effort, maintaining free software. And as you mentioned, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: hi! how did you install pdb on cygwin? I searched for in in the 'Uninstalled' packages but couldn't find it.

Comment: @Chan Kim via apt-cyg https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg